# При нажатии на td возникает ошибка "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded". С чем это связано? Я не нашел решения

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var oldCell;
    var oldText;
    $("td.tdTime").hover(
        function () {
            oldCell = $(this).children(".rotate");
            var cell = $(this).children(".rotate");
            oldText = cell.text();
            cell.text('Удалить!');
        },
        function () {
            oldCell.text(oldText);
        });
});

function deleteDay(tdObj) {
    td = $(tdObj);
    var idZanyatiya = td.attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "DeleteDay",
        data: { Facultet_ID: Facultet_ID, Gruppa_ID: Gruppa_ID, Disciplina_ID: Disciplina_ID, PrepodID: Prepod_ID, IDZanyatiya: idZanyatiya }
    });
}
```

```
       @foreach (BRSGSTOU.Models.tableZanyatiy z in ViewBag.ChisloZanyatiy)
        {
            if (Gruppa_ID == z.ID_Gruppi.ToString() && Disciplina_ID == z.ID_Disciplini.ToString())
            {

            <td id="@z.ID" onclick="deleteDay(this)" class="tdTime" style="max-height:80px;padding-top:65px; padding-bottom:5px;">
                <div class="rotate">@z.Vremya.ToString("d")</div>
            </td>
            }
        }
```

Comment: ошибка на клиенте или на сервере?

Comment: ошибка на клиенте

Comment: В коде вопроса нет ничего, что может вызвать такую ошибку. Откуда берутся переменные `Facultet_ID`, `Gruppa_ID` и другие?

Comment: Это C# переменные со своими значениями. Они не пустые. Я проверял

Comment: Откуда возьмутся C# переменные в строке javascript'a `data: { Facultet_ID: Facultet_ID, ...`?

Comment: Думал они передают значения. Создал js переменные и присвоил им значения C# переменных. Все заработало!

Answer (score 1):

> Откуда возьмутся C# переменные в строке javascript'a data: { Facultet_ID: Facultet_ID, ...?Igor

Думал они передают значения. Создал js переменные и присвоил им значения C# переменных. Все заработало!